# Chat is notifying me incorrectly

Tags: bug, chat

I got several notifications from The Heap that should have targeted another user.

The notification link to chat is:

http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15284325?noredirect=1#15284325

It should have notified this user:  http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/115579/max

I imagine the issue only occurs when there is a user with a 3 character name that exactly matches the leading 3 characters of a user who has been in chat prior.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue, and not specific to [Database Administrators](http://dba.stackexchange.com). There have been some attempts to fix the problem, but they're not foolproof. See these:

- [Stack Exchange chat name mention inbox confusion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66290/stack-exchange-chat-name-mention-inbox-confusion)
- [Getting Marc's chat notifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73931/getting-marcs-chat-notifications)
- [What are the rules for when chat messages appear in a user's inbox?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/938/what-are-the-rules-for-when-chat-messages-appear-in-a-users-inbox/939#939)

Comment: Thanks, Aaron.  I should have checked the main meta site first!

Answer (score 2):

Some folk with common names go as far as to mix in a unicode character, eg Daи for Dan. Just don't mess with the first letter!

You could be Ma✗, Maẋ or Maẍ Vernon, whichever takes your fancy ;)

Comment: Another idea: `Mach2`